# c# how to create XML file with XSD schemas

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Sample XML file generated by XMLSpy v2013 (http://www.altova.com)-->
<ftc:FATCA_OECD version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v2 FatcaXML_v2.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ftc="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v2" xmlns:sfa="urn:oecd:ties:stffatcatypes:v2">
    <ftc:MessageSpec>
        <sfa:SendingCompanyIN>S519K4.99999.SL.392</sfa:SendingCompanyIN>
        <sfa:TransmittingCountry>JP</sfa:TransmittingCountry>
        <sfa:ReceivingCountry>US</sfa:ReceivingCountry>
        <sfa:MessageType>FATCA</sfa:MessageType>
        <sfa:MessageRefId>DBA6455E-8454-47D9-914B-FEE48E4EF3AA</sfa:MessageRefId>
        <sfa:ReportingPeriod>2016-12-31</sfa:ReportingPeriod>
        <sfa:Timestamp>2017-01-17T09:30:47Z</sfa:Timestamp>
    </ftc:MessageSpec>
</ftc:FATCA_OECD>
```

my code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            doc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);

            XmlElement element1 = doc.CreateElement("<ftc:FATCA_OECD version=\"2.0\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v2 FatcaXML_v2.0.xsd\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:ftc=\"urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v2\" xmlns:sfa=\"urn:oecd:ties:stffatcatypes:v2\">");
            doc.AppendChild(element1);

            XmlElement element2 = doc.CreateElement("ftc:MessageSpec");
            element1.AppendChild(element2);

            XmlElement element3 = doc.CreateElement("sfa:SendingCompanyIN");
            XmlText text1 = doc.CreateTextNode(txt_SendingCompanyIN.Text);
            element3.AppendChild(text1);
            element2.AppendChild(element3);

            XmlElement element4 = doc.CreateElement("sfa:TransmittingCountry");
            XmlText text2 = doc.CreateTextNode(txt_TransmittingCountry.Text);
            element4.AppendChild(text2);
            element2.AppendChild(element4);

            XmlElement element5 = doc.CreateElement("sfa:ReceivingCountry");
            XmlText text3 = doc.CreateTextNode(txt_ResCountryCode.Text);
            element4.AppendChild(text3);
            element2.AppendChild(element4);
```

I need to create the following XML and I'm trying to do this using XDocument. but fail cannot create xml file?

how can i create a xsd schema for this xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication48
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            //<!--Sample XML file generated by XMLSpy v2013 (http://www.altova.com)-->
            //<ftc:FATCA_OECD version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v2 FatcaXML_v2.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ftc="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v2" xmlns:sfa="urn:oecd:ties:stffatcatypes:v2">
            //    <ftc:MessageSpec>
            //        <sfa:SendingCompanyIN>S519K4.99999.SL.392</sfa:SendingCompanyIN>
            //        <sfa:TransmittingCountry>JP</sfa:TransmittingCountry>
            //        <sfa:ReceivingCountry>US</sfa:ReceivingCountry>
            //        <sfa:MessageType>FATCA</sfa:MessageType>
            //        <sfa:MessageRefId>DBA6455E-8454-47D9-914B-FEE48E4EF3AA</sfa:MessageRefId>
            //        <sfa:ReportingPeriod>2016-12-31</sfa:ReportingPeriod>
            //        <sfa:Timestamp>2017-01-17T09:30:47Z</sfa:Timestamp>
            //    </ftc:MessageSpec>
            //</ftc:FATCA_OECD>
            string header =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                "<ftc:FATCA_OECD" +
                   " version=\"2.0\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v2 FatcaXML_v2.0.xsd\"" +
                   " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"" +
                   " xmlns:ftc=\"urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v2\"" +
                   " xmlns:sfa=\"urn:oecd:ties:stffatcatypes:v2\">" +
                "</ftc:FATCA_OECD>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);  
            XElement FATCA_OECD = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace ftcNS = FATCA_OECD.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("ftc");
            XNamespace sfaNS = FATCA_OECD.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("sfa");

            XElement MessageSpec = new XElement(ftcNS + "MessageSpec", new object[] {
               new XElement(sfaNS + "SendingCompanyIN", "S519K4.99999.SL.392"),
               new XElement(sfaNS + "TransmittingCountry", "JP"),
               new XElement(sfaNS + "ReceivingCountry", "US"),
               new XElement(sfaNS + "MessageType", "FATCA"),
               new XElement(sfaNS + "MessageRefId", "DBA6455E-8454-47D9-914B-FEE48E4EF3AA"),
               new XElement(sfaNS + "ReportingPeriod", "2016-12-31"),
               new XElement(sfaNS + "Timestamp", "2017-01-17T09:30:47Z"),
            });



            FATCA_OECD.Add(MessageSpec);




        }
    }

}
```